# ASP.NET Core WebAPI 3.1 multiple parameters vs Complex object httpget

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Not done API for a while and wanted to make sure what is the best practice to make a call when you need to pass multiple parameters in an `HttpGet`

Option 1

```
[HttpGet("getpet", Name = nameof(GetPet))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PetResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<<PetResponse>> GetById(
[FromQuery]int id,
[FromQuery]bool dogsOnly)
```

Option 2
use a Complex Object.

```
[HttpGet("getpet", Name = nameof(GetPet))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PetResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<<PetResponse>>  GetById([FromQuery]PetRequest request)
```

public class PetRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool DogsOnly { get; set; }
}

Any suggestions or limitation of any of the approach eg test in postman?

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions or limitation of any of the approach eg test in
>   postman?

The two option use the same way to test on Postman.

If your query strings would not change,the two options are all acceptable.But if you need to change the query string afterwards and the same query strings appear many times in your application,creating a `PetRequest` model is much better.